# Launching on demand jar program using Liferay

Tags: spring, jar, liferay, spring-batch, portlet

I have created a jar program that converts some XML files into CSV (using spring batch). I'd like to go further and create a portlet into Liferay to allow people launching this jar file on demand, with history by user.

The jar file will be in the same server as Liferay.

Could you please help me on how to design such a portlet ?

Thank you

Comment: I would say that Stackoverflow is not the right platform for such a question. Just start to write such a portlet and ask a more specific question here.

Comment: Thank you for your response, my question was about knowing which will be the best solution before starting to code: should I include the jar in WEB-inf/lib and invoke the main class, or is there a better solution

Comment: Asking for "what is better" is off topic as well (please read [help/on-topic])

Comment: So where can I kindly ask this question to have some advise please ?

Comment: The problem is not the place, but the question. Your question is very broad (and has nothing to do with Liferay by the way). And if you like to make it more specific: You can at any time edit you question (which is different from editing a post on other platforms).